Blazor RedirectToLogin infinite loop
Goal
I want to route to my login page when I am not authorized.
I use AspNet with Entity Framework in a MudBlazor WebApp
Problem
The problem is that my browser keeps saying
The page isn’t redirecting properly

When I put a breakpoint in my OnInitializedAsync in RedirectToLogin.razor i recognize an infinite loop.
What I tried

using LoginPage directly

<NotAuthorized>
   <LoginPage/>
</NotAuthorized>

But then there is no navigation URI in the browsers searchbar

wrapping the LoginPage in LoginLayout results in infinite loop also

<NotAuthorized>
   <LayoutView Layout="typeof(LoginLayout)">
      <RedirectToLogin/>
   </LayoutView>
</NotAuthorized>


using @attribute [Authorize] redirects always to Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
using @attribute [Authorize] and changing LoginPage to @page "/Account/Login" and using this code

<AuthorizeView>
  <Authorized>
     <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>
  </Authorized>
  <NotAuthorized>
     <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(LoginLayout)" />
  </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

seems to work but I cant use a custom route except Account/Login
Code
Routes.razor
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeView>
                <Authorized>
                    <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)"/>
                </Authorized>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin/>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

MainLayout.razor
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="1">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="@(e => DrawerToggle())" />
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.End" />
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="_drawerOpen" Elevation="2">
        <MudDrawerHeader>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Class="mt-1">MyApp</MudText>
        </MudDrawerHeader>
        <NavMenu/>
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        @Body
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
    bool _drawerOpen = true;

    void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
    }
}

RedirectToLogin.razor
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Login", forceLoad: true);
    }
}

LoginLayout.razor
<MudLayout>
    <p>LoginLayout</p>
    <MudMainContent>
        @Body
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
}

LoginPage.razor
@page "/Login"

<h3>LoginPage</h3>

@code {

}

And App.razor and Program.cs maybe it helps...
App.razor
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CompanyKnowledgeAIClient.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico" />

    @* Mudblazor - Add font and style references *@
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    @* Mudblazor - Add script reference *@
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add DbContexts
builder.Services.AddDbContext<PostgresDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MySqlDbContext>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

// MudBlazor Services
builder.Services.AddMudServices();

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

// Detailed error output on circuit
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });

// Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();

// Identity
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MySqlDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();


Not sure if it's the best solution, but one thing you can do is to redirect directly from MainLayout.
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <MudLayout>
        ...
        </MudLayout>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
    @{
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Login", forceLoad: true);
    }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

